# Added support for calling a Javascript function to an applet and now get 404 No Context from Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, applet

I have changed an applet embedded in a web page from a Tomcat 6 web application to be able to call Javascript functions (import netscape.javascript.*;) and now all of a sudden I get 404 error when accessing the web page with IE9 text:

Error 404 - Not Found.
No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are: 
html_javascript(/html_javascript)

and the same from Chrome.

Is there some additional thing I need to do to make this work?  why this error?

Comment: Do you have an URL to the broken applet that you can share?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - see my answer below.  fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding MAYSCRIPT to the applet tag in the html.

Like this:

```
<applet code="com.example.MyApplet.class" name="myapplet"  codebase="http://localhost:8080/example/classes" align="baseline"
 width="200" height="200" MAYSCRIPT>
<PARAM NAME="model" VALUE="models/HyaluronicAcid.xyz">
alt="Your browser understands the &lt;APPLET&gt; tag but isn't running the applet, for some reason."
Your browser is completely ignoring the &lt;APPLET&gt; tag!
</applet>
```